# c# Looking for data structure which can take muliple values to create a key

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm looking for a data structure which can take muliple input values to generate a key, a Guid key for instance, store the key and the values which are returned from xpath:regexp node lookups, call it a domain registry, and then be able to take the key and store another chunk of data, say Arbitory... into for instance, into an IDictionary

Then be able to take that that selfsame returned xpath:regexp xml node lookup data and lookup the data structure for the key, to look into the IDictionary and return Arbitory.

It seems fairly simple on the surface, but the Key could have 2 Guid, plus 1..N xpath:regexp lookup. An example of the xpath:regexp lookup would be.

/idmef:IDMEF-Message/idmef:Alert/idmef:Classification/@text: [Ll]ogin|[Aa]uthentication

Placement variables are used to mark the returned xml, so the whole xml message is $0, while $1 would be Login Authentication, $2 would be the next xpath:regexp lookup. Potentially their could be 1.N xpath:regexp lookups into the xml message.

So say I used string appendage to generate the key, the key could be potentially 100's of characaters long, because its made up of 2 guid + 1.N of $0, $1, etc. That was the original way I was planning to do it. But appending returned string would be massively inefficient.

So the question is - Is their a C# data structure where a key generator can take 1.N values and return a unique key, which can be used again to return that key using the same 1.N values.

I hope it's fairly clear what i'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

scope_creep

Comment: I don't think i'm looking for custom code, as much as a general purpose data structure for this type of use.

Comment: Let me say on behalf of the SO community: huh?

Comment: Do I need to rewrite it.

Comment: I'm looking for suggestions on how to create a key for an IDictionary where the key can consist of 2 Guids + 1.N strings of xml. It must be unique.

Bob.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question (a definite possibility), you can dump the 2 Guids and the variable number of XML strings into a string[] array, and use the array object's GetHashCode() to generate the key. Or create a class/struct with separate string properties for the Guids and the variable-length array of XML, and use its GetHashCode() for the key.

Comment: GetHashCode() returns an int, so the keys won't be *truly* unique, but I'd guess they'd be unique enough for most porpoises.

Comment: I found the GetHashCode() yesterday, but unfortunately the keys need to be unique, otherwise it would have been ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
I changed the data structure to remove the above limitation.
Thanks for the help MusiGenesis.
Bob.